# How to use sendEmailVerification() in firebase 9

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, firebase-authentication

I have been trying to use the sendEmailVerification() method in my firebase 9 app but all the tutorials/docs on the internet seem to use firebase 8 and thus have different syntax to the one used in firebase 9. Even the firebase docs seem to be outdated. Bellow is my best attempt at trying to use this method, and it does not work. To be clear the desired behavior is for a verification email to be sent and then wait for the email to be verified before proceeding to the homescreen. Currently no email is sent and when you create an account it logs you straight in. No errors are displayed either. I would be very grateful for any help provided.

```
  const handleCreateAccount = async () => {
    if (password == password2) {
      try {
        const { user } = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        await user.sendEmailVerification();
        setVerifyMessage("Verification mail sent")
      } catch (error) {
        setDisplayError(error.message)
      }
    } else {
      setDisplayError("The passwords don't match")
    }
  }
```

Comment: "*and it does not work*" - so, what does it do? Just saying "[it doesn't work](https://overflow.tips/problematic-questions#why-doesnt-it-work--what-am-i-missing-here)" isn't enough information to work with, and the question might be [closed as needing debugging information](https://overflow.tips/why-question-closed#needs-detail-or-clarity-and-needs-debugging-details). Are there errors? Please edit the question to explain in more detail what you observe this code doing that's different than what you expect. Include logging and errors to illustrate.

Comment: *firebaser here* "Even the firebase docs seem to be outdated." Can you provide a link to the outdated documentation, so we can get it updated?